# Writing into multiple text files at a time

Tags: c#, filestream

I have the data that needs too be logged into 6 different text files.Currently i'm using streamwriter to write the data into the textfiles one after the other.
Like this

```
using (StreamWriter _writer = File.AppendText(_filePath))
{                                   
    _writer.WriteLine("....Some Text ...");               
}
```

But this takes considerable amount of time.Is there a way to write into all the text files at the same time ?

Comment: I/O will be your overhead

Comment: Try [Logging framework NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) They already implement some kind of caching I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of stream writers and use `Parallel.Foreach` over them to write to multiple files concurrently.

```
var streamWriters = new List<StreamWriter>();
streamWriters.Add(new StreamWriter("1.txt"));
streamWriters.Add(new StreamWriter("2.txt"));
streamWriters.Add(new StreamWriter("3.txt"));
streamWriters.Add(new StreamWriter("4.txt"));
streamWriters.Add(new StreamWriter("5.txt"));
streamWriters.Add(new StreamWriter("6.txt"));

Parallel.ForEach(streamWriters, s => { s.Write("some text"); s.Dispose(); });
```

This may improve some of your performance.